# Automatic type conversion in Java?

Tags: java, type-conversion, overloading

Is there a way to do automatic implicit type conversion in Java? For example, say I have two types, 'FooSet' and 'BarSet' which both are representations of a Set. It is easy to convert between the types, such that I have written two utility methods:

```
/** Given a BarSet, returns a FooSet */
public FooSet barTOfoo(BarSet input) { /* ... */ }

/** Given a FooSet, returns a BarSet */
public BarSet fooTObar(FooSet input) { /* ... */ }
```

Now say there's a method like this that I want to call:

```
public void doSomething(FooSet data) {
    /* .. */
}
```

But all I have is a `BarSet myBarSet`...it means extra typing, like:

```
doSomething(barTOfoo(myBarSet));
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler that certain types can automatically be cast to other types? I know this is possible in C++ with overloading, but I can't find a way in Java. I want to just be able to type:

```
doSomething(myBarSet);
```

And the compiler knows to automatically call `barTOfoo()`

Comment: More details...I have two separate libraries which I cannot change, and they both use similar but incompatible data structures. I often need to get data from one library, manipulate it, then pass it to the other library. My code ends up being littered with fooTObar and barTOfoo calls everywhere.

Comment: This type of glue between similar but not quite directly compatable APIs is definitely not one of Java's strengths. There is a lot of boilerplate to get it done.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the two libraries are JSON-based objects (for talking to a webservice) and AMF-based objects (for talking to Flash clients via a persistent RMTP connection). Both AMF and JSON have notions of arrays, lists, associative arrays, objects, etc. So in Java I'm constantly converting between AMFDataArray and JSONArray, AMFDataObj and JSONObject, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is short: It's possible with overloading in C++ but there is no way to do that in Java.

Comment: Also possible in C# and many other sane languages, because it's a very useful function.

Answer (score 2):

You could overload your methods, something like this:

```
public void doSomething(FooSet data) {
    /* .. */
}

public void doSomething(BarSet data) {
    doSomething(barTOfoo(data));
}
```

Comment: doSomething is a method I cannot modify, it's in an external library. But I guess writing my own overloaded methods which call the external method is an option.

Comment: @davr yes, I saw that edit after I wrote my answer. I suppose that another layer in between your code and the library could be a bit of a nuisance, but it depends on how much of a nuisance barTOfoo and fooTObar is...  It will also allow you to change how the library code is implemented if it's functionality changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could do both together:

(1) Write wrapper methods which do conversion on the back-scenes.

(2) If your objects have proper `hashCode` overriden method, the wrapper methods may manage a very simple and fast cache, which you can build yourself with simple `Map` implementation and probably synchronization (if you use the objects concurrently at all).

That will get you rid of both converting between the two types all the time and probably of performance concerns. Even if you go against caching, I would still recommend (as other posters said) to use wrapping methods. That at least saves you lots of unnecessary typing.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Overloading** works in the opposite way, you declare two methods on the receiver object:

```
public void doSomething(FooSet data)
{
    /* .. */
}

public void doSomething(BarSet data)
{
    doSomething(barToFoo(data));
}
```

<strike>then thanks to **Dynamic Binding** ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_binding_%28computer_science%29)) the right method is choosen at run-time.</strike>

Of course **overloading** in Java is scoped at object-level (since calls are restricted to instances or class declarations), but it works in the same way.

In your case you can try by extending the class also if it's in an external library, since it's java you should be able to do it, and add the method or by using *reflection* ([java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)) to add the method dynamically.

Comment: doSomething is a method I cannot modify, it's in an external library. But I guess writing my own overloaded methods which call the external method is an option.

Comment: It is not an example of Dynamic Binding by any means. It is just overloading, it happens at compile time based on declared types of variables.

Answer (score 0):

*Automatic* type conversion isn't supported (you want Scala's [implicit type conversions](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-6) for that).

But you could try using a [Variant](https://github.com/youdevise/variance) type as a junction-box for switching between types:

```
/** Given a BarSet, returns a FooSet */
public Function<BarSet, FooSet> barTofoo = new Function<BarSet, FooSet>() {
    @Override public FooSet apply(BarSet input) { /* ... */ }
}

/** Given a FooSet, returns a BarSet */
public Function<FooSet, BarSet> fooToBar = new Function<FooSet, BarSet>() {
    @Override public BarSet apply(FooSet input) { /* ... */ }
}

/** Create a type conversion context in which both of these conversions are registered */
TypeConversionContext fooBarConversionContext = MatchingTypeConversionContext.builder()
    .register(FooSet.class, BarSet.class, fooToBar)
    .register(BarSet.class, FooSet.class, barToFoo)
    .build();

/** Put a FooSet into a Variant, bound to our type conversion context */
FooSet fooSet = new FooSet();
Variant data = Variant.of(fooSet).in(fooBarConversionContext);

/** Pull a BarSet out of the Variant */
public void doSomething(Variant data) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(data.isConvertibleTo(BarSet.class);
    BarSet barSet = data.as(BarSet.class);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, however it's typical Java over-verbosity to me. I'd end up complicating things instead of simplifying them like I wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

Java was created with visibility in mind. Every programmer should be able read just one line and understand what is happening there. This is why it doesn't have operator overloading, this is why it doesn't have any kind of automatic custom type conversion. So, unless you write your own wrappers around one of the library that will accept types from other library and explicitly convert them, you are out of luck there.

Comment: I guess that explains why you have to use String.equals instead of == all the time...so dumb.

Comment: @davr, exactly, they wanted you to spot right on is it references or actual content is being compared.