# Change default return of an object in Java

Tags: java

The default return of an object in Java is to return the toString method, is there a way to change this behavior to for example return a number or some other type or is this just a core unchangeable component of the language?

```
Test test = new Test();
blankMethod(test);
```

I am not sure why people are saying my assumption is wrong... if I Override the toString method of object it will output that new toString method...

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    System.out.println("This method is run when the object is used as a parameter");
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. The value of reference type is the value of a reference to the object. Separately, there is an overloaded `println` method which accepts an argument of type `Object` and invokes its `toString` method.

Comment: `"The default return of an object in Java is to return the toString method"` -- where did you find this bit of information?

Comment: Your confusing what `PrintStream#println(...)` does, which is to call `toString()` on an object, with an innate property of an object. These are two completely different things.

Comment: It could be improved by getting rid of the bad premise, and giving more information about what CodeCamper is trying to achieve.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: you are right, apologies to CodeCamper.

Comment: To be fair, this is a real edge case of the language and for newcomers I can see how this would trip them up.

Comment: And in my comment, it should be should be `"You're ..."`. Ugh.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if my assumption is wrong then how come when I overload the toString method of object it outputs my new toString method?

Comment: Read up on inheritance.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I understand inheritance, I understand abstract classes, classes, interface.... I am not sure why you are saying my assumption is wrong. In my code example if you just pass object as a parameter it magically runs the toString method... I added code to show you as an example... I was only using the System.out.println to demonstrate the behavior of calling "object"... ugh... semantic confusion...

Comment: [Here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28java.lang.Object%29) the implementation of `PrintStream#println(Object)`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels read the code I added, when you pass an object into a parameter it runs the toString method... just a trivial question of whether you can change this default behavior.

Comment: When you pass a object as an argument **to `PrintStream#println(Object)`**. This is specific to this method.

Comment: @CodeCamper: no, you can only change the `toString()` returned, that's all. But regardless, `toString()` is not to be used in production code, but rather mainly for debugging purposes, so for an end product, this is a moot question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think you understand my question... not sure how to reword this... I guess the answer is no, I remember there was a way to do this in C#...

Comment: @CodeCamper I **know** I don't understand your question. It might be helpful to go up a level, and explain what you are trying to achieve, or even show the C# code that does what you want.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan in C# it can be accomplished using `static implicit operator`. It is interesting in Java that the only implicit operator of an object is actually a String and that behavior cannot be changed. Would have been a nice thing to add in Java 8...

Comment: @CodeCamper Try Scala.

Comment: I am a fan of Scala School by Twitter (https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually calling

[PrintStream.println(Object x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println)

instead of

[public void println(String x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println)

The `PrintStream.println(Object x)` implementation is below:

```
public void println(Object x) {
     String s = String.valueOf(x);
     synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

The method calls `String.valueOf(x)` whose implementation is below:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
   return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Note that the `Object.toString()` method is being called.

**Notes on implicit conversion**

An `Object` is only implicitly converted to a `String` using the `toString` method when the string concatenation operator (`+`) is invoked. More exactly the conversion works as follows:

> A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value...
>
> This reference value is then converted to type String by string conversion.
> Now only reference values need to be considered.
>
> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four
> ASCII characters n, u, l, l). Otherwise, the conversion is performed
> as if by an invocation of the toString method of the referenced object
> with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the toString method
> is null, then the string "null" is used instead.
>
> The toString method is defined by the primordial class Object"

[Java Language Specification 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.18.1)

One language (of many) that expand on the idea of implicit conversions is Scala which allows one to bring a conversion (e.g., A -> B) into scope which is then invoked whenever some type (A) is passed as an argument when a different type (B) is required.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, because use my override method in my updated question. You will see the toString method is always run. When you use the object as any parameter.

Comment: This answer also contradicts the documentation. Ultimately, the conversion is done by [String.valueOf(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29): "if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.". In this case, it is not null.

Comment: I was paraphrasing, but since it is creating confusion I will update the answer.

Comment: @CodeCamper I updated my answer to hopefully clarify. I expanded on implicit conversions in Java and other languages.

Answer (score 2):

> The default return of an object in Java is to return the toString method

That's how `PrintStream.println` works. Any object in java extends `java.lang.Object` and therefore inherits `Object` behavior. In particular, any method which takes `Object` as an argument, also can take any object of another type. However, you can override any `public` or `protected` method defined in `Object`. In your case you should override `toString()` method in `Test` class, otherwise if you pass `Test` object to `PrintWriter.println()`, it'll use `toString` from superclass (`Object` in your case). So, if i understood your question correctly, the answer is **no**.

Update: your terminology is wrong. There is no *default return of an object* in java. Returning `Object.toString` is the default behavior only for `PrintStream.println(Object)`.

Update2: more widely, Java doesn't support implicit type conversion except [upcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class). In your case, `Test` extends `Object`, but it doesn't extend `String` (actually, `String` is final and therefore you can't extend it). So, if you try to pass `Test` object to method which only takes `String`, you'll get compilation error because `String` and `Test` belong to different branches of class hierarchy.

Comment: If you create a blank method and pass the object in I am pretty certain it still runs the toString method.

Comment: If you pass `Test` object to a method which only takes `String`, you'll get compilation error. No implicit `toString()` calls.

Comment: You are right, that is really strange... when you pass an object parameter the default behavior of every object is to return a String via toString... but you can't implicitly return an object where a String is required even though I can't change it and every object MUST return a String when the object is requested... Not very logical to me...

Comment: Nothing strange. You're saying about [automatic type convertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406155/automatic-type-conversion-in-java). So, the answer is simple: java doesn't support implicit type convertion except upcasting.

Answer (score 1):

This answers "why people are saying my assumption is wrong".

Here is a simple program:

```
public class Test {
  public String toString(){
    return "I am a Test object.";
  }

  public int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test object = new Test();
    System.out.println(object);
    System.out.println(object.add(2,2));
    System.out.println(adder(object));
  }

  public static int adder(Test test){
    return test.add(3,5);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
I am a Test object.
4
8
```

The `System.out.println` method has to turn its argument into a String, one way or another. If it is passed an object reference, it uses its toString() method. If it is passed a primitive, such as an `int` expression, it converts it in an appropriate way.

It is nothing to do with what is being returned.

It also has nothing to do with any automatic conversion on passing a reference as an argument. See the third line of output, which depends on using the `Test` reference I passed to `adder` as a `Test`, not a `String`.

If you want to change what println prints, do what I did above, and pass it something different.