# java dollar symbol com.package.Foo.$$$.Bar issue

Tags: java, reflection

I am doing a webservice call and it responds with model class called `Foo`. `Foo` is not extending any other class.

```
Foo data = call();
```

I can access all data fields normally. `String str = data.getData();`

However if I do `System.out.println(data.toString())`; 
I am getting back the following output: `com.package.Foo.$$$.Bar@2938ac9a`

I suspect that web framework is doing some reflection magic around responses and wrapping it with proxy class. Since `Bar` is extending `Foo` on application level I can't notice anything and still can access all data I need. But...

**Problem:**

When I am trying to serialise Foo data; as a result I am getting a lot of unexpected data and fields.

I wonder if someone can explain me what does `$$$` mean in java and **how do I convert `Bar` object back to `Foo`?**

Comment: I believe it's just an auto-generated class name.

Comment: any ideas how to convert Bar to Foo?

Comment: Unless your `Foo` class has a copy constructor, I don't think there's an easy way.  What kind of serialisation are you doing that's leading to issues?

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a wrapper that some library uses to hide their implementation, with auto-generated code. Another instance (slightly different) can be caught while using Hibernate, which relies on the `Proxy` class from the `com.sun.proxy` package:

```
...
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getSingleResult(Unknown Source) // Who would name its class 'Proxy38' ?
...
```

See [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633534/what-is-com-sun-proxy-proxy) for more details.

You would have to write your own wrapper in order to succeed:

```
public Foo barToFoo(Bar data)    {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.name = data.getName();
    ...
    ...
    return foo;
}
```

This is one of your safest options. You keep control on the data, you can still access it, you are converting it back to `Foo` the way **you** want (and not some tricky conversion or hidden implementation), and you can handle any case you like (`null` data, exceptions, etc).

**EDIT**

> It should happen automatically. Is there any solution [...] ?

It looks like there are not, unfortunately. [There is an overloading solution in C++, but not in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406155/automatic-type-conversion-in-java).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that should work but the only problem is that conversion should happen automatically. Do you know if there are any solutions available? Given object and Destination type they will convert it automatically using same name for getters and setters?

Comment: `(Foo) data.toString()` will not compile.

Comment: Also, there is no automated solution in C++ - the answer you're linking to is really just saying that you can hide the code in an overloaded conversion operator.

Comment: Well, as that was the top answer in a question about automation, I thought useful to link it. I'll make it clearer, thank you.